# android sqlite database returns nothing

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my method

```
public int getamount(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(buy) FROM " + table_name, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(col_6));
    c.close();
    return i;

    }
```

This is my main activity

```
public void button_res(View view) {
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.textView7)) {
     total();
    }
}

public void total(){
    Integer i = myDb.getamount();
    textView7.setText(i);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

when i click my button it shows me nothing.

Comment: I guess `total` is never called; but nobody here knows how you have wired up `button_res`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a column named "SUM(buy)" or something like that (the exact name is not guaranteed), so searching for a column with the name specified by `col_6` will not work.

You could force the column to have a specific name:

```sql
SELECT SUM(buy) AS xxx FROM ...
```

or you could just take the first column of the result:

```
int i = c.getInt(0);
```

but the easiest way to implement this is to use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) that hides the cursor management:

```
public int getamount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return (int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
            "SELECT SUM(buy) FROM " + table_name, null);
}
```

Comment: i do as u say but still nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong: there's only one colum in your cursor, which is the sum.
So this is wrong:

```
int i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(col_6));
```

It must be:

```
int i = c.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public int getamount()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(buy) as amount FROM " + table_name, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));
        c.close();
        return i;
    }
```